# Fields on uncountable sets

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I recently found out that when the underlying set is countably infinite, the only field structure that can be added to it will make it isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$ (is this correct?)
So, i was wondering, how many (up to isomorphism) different structures can be given to a set of cardinality same as $\mathbb{R}$ (of the continuum)? I only know of $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{C}$ and the fields $\mathbb{Q}_p$ of p-adic numbers, for each prime p. Are there more?

Comment: $\Bbb{Q}$ is NOT the unique infinite countable field. For example, all [algebraic number fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_number_field) are countable. Moreover, if $k$ denotes any infinite field, $k(X)$ (the field of rational functions on $k$) is a new infinite field with the same cardinality of $k$.

Comment: Among other fields of cardinality $c$, consider rational function fields $\mathbb K(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$ where $\mathbb K$ is a field of cardinality $c$ and $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ are indeterminates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User Crostul mentions an important class of counter-examples to your first question, and also the limit of finite fields can be countable with characteristic $p$.

Consider the characteristic $0$ case. 
A countably generated transcendental extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ will be countable, and assuming the continuum hypothesis it can be at most generated by $2^{\aleph}$ elements. This leaves the case that $K > \mathbb{Q}$ is the function field of some quotient of $\mathbb{Q}[x_i]$ where $i$ ranges a set with cardinality of the continuum. By similar arguments, the case of characteristic $p$ can be given a similar description, which doesn't really shed light onto the structure of these fields. Still, it makes it clear (I think) that *many* such fields exist.